# Laravel: How to prevent eloquent model save using events inside a package?

Tags: php, events, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to prevent a model from saving to database, if it has certain value in a property.

Inside service provider:

```
public function register()
{
  $this->registerSaveRelated();
  $this->registerEvents();
}

public function registerEvents()
{
  $app = $this->app;

  $app['events']->listen('eloquent.saving*', function ($model) use ($app) {
    $app['my_service']->checkModel($model);
  });
}

public function registerSaveRelated(){
// More code...
```

`checkModel($model)` gets fired, as expected. However, nothing happens if I return false. The model continues to save. What is the correct way to do it?

It needs to be done in the package, not model. So Model::saving() is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that I can think of.

A. Use `Model::saving()` and just differentiate between the packages using a boolean or other simple logic.

B. Override the save method and put the logic in that function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.  You are correct that `checkModel` needs to return true or false.  The important part, however, is what the closure passed to `listen` returns.  That is what determines whether it saves or not.  Right now its not returning anything.  Try adding `return` like so:

```
public function registerEvents()
{
  $app = $this->app;

  $app['events']->listen('eloquent.saving*', function ($model) use ($app) {
    return $app['my_service']->checkModel($model);
  });
}
```